# How to export vault secrets as zip file

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Is there a way to export vault secret data from one vault instance, and then import to another vault instance?

Example:
Export secrets from the source instance with the path secret/vault/path and import to the destination empty vault instance.

Comment: did you figure out what worked best for you?

Answer (score 8):

I am not aware of a 'native' way to do this. You will need to iterate over the requested secrets and export them to file (and import them in the same way).

You can try to use one of the following projects that attempt to do it:

[Vault backup](https://github.com/shaneramey/vault-backup)

[Vault backup migrator](https://github.com/adamdecaf/vault-backend-migrator)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will try this out

Answer (score 8):

I have written an open source cli tool called Medusa that can export and import your Vault secrets on different Vault instances.
The tool can handle a full tree structure in both import and export. It also supports end to end encryption of your secrets between export and import between Vault instances so that your secrets are always secure.
https://github.com/jonasvinther/medusa

```
export VAULT_ADDR=https://192.168.86.41:8201
export VAULT_SKIP_VERIFY=true
export VAULT_TOKEN=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

./medusa export kv/path/to/secret --format="yaml" --output="my-secrets.txt"
./medusa import kv/path/to/new/secret ./my-secrets.txt
```